# Use flag value in new package

Tags: go, func

I write on Golang. I create flag and use it in main package. But now I whant use it in new package. How can I do this? 
`myFlag   = flagSet.Int("MyFlag", 0, "Test")` - this I wrote in Main package.
I whant change variable in new package from console. But I don't know what write in new package for use this flag.

Answer (score 0):

As a direct answer - you can use exported global variables for the flag values. These can be used from other packages.

E.g:

```
var Verbose = flag.Bool("v", false, "show verbose progress message")
```

If this is defined globally in package `foo`, then `foo.Verbose` can be used from other packages that import `foo`.

---

Stylistically, exported global variables should be used sparingly, and exporting one from the main package to use in another package is a particular code smell. You're making your package's behavior dependent on global state elsewhere, making it fragile and harder to test. It would be much better for your package to have some sort of configuration `struct` and fill it in when it's used from main, potentially using main's flags.